# pdf of a function angle $θ$

Tags: probability

I have the function $t(\theta)=4/(4+C\cos(θ)+D(\cos(θ))^2))^2 $  where $C, D>0$
the parameters   C, D are $C= 4 A$ and $D=A^2+B^2$.

The $θ$ follow is uniform distridbuted
$[0 ,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ then the pdf  is  $g(θ)=1/(π/2-0)=2/π$.

I want to find the pdf of $t$.
Αccording to theory the pdf of $t$ is $f(t)=\frac{1}{|\frac{dt}{d\theta}|}g(θ)$

the $$\frac{dt}{dθ}=\frac{4(C\sin(θ)+2D\sin(θ)\cos(θ)}{(4+C\cos(θ)+D(\cos(θ))^2))^2}$$

The $\cos (θ)$ has two solutions
$$\cos(θ)=(−C t+\sqrt{(C^2-16 D)t+16D)})/(2 D t)$$

$$\cos(θ)=(−C t-\sqrt{(C^2-16 D) t+16D)})/(2 D t)$$

I keep the first  root because in the  range  $0<θ<π/2$ and $\cos (θ)>0$ .

Τhe  $\cos (θ)$ ( first  equation  is
positive in  range    $ t_{1} <t <t_{2} $

where $t_{1}=16D/((2 D+C)^2−(C^2−16 D)) $ and $t_2=1$

My results are  correct?
I make  a Monte carlo Code  to compare my results  for some values of  A and B  the MC agree  with  theoretical pdf  but  for others   values  there differnces

Thank you, George

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$t=\frac{4}{\left(c \cos (\theta )+d \cos ^2(\theta )+4\right)^2}$$

with $0<\theta<\pi/2$, $c>0$, and $d>0$.  You need to be able to get $\theta$ in terms of $t$:

$$\theta=\text{ArcCos}\left[\frac{\sqrt{c^2+\frac{8 d}{\sqrt{t}}-16 d}-c}{2 d}\right]$$

The Jacobian is then

$$J=\frac{d\theta}{dt}= \frac{1}{t^{3/2} \sqrt{1-\frac{\left(-\sqrt{c^2+\frac{8 d}{\sqrt{t}}-16 d}-c\right)^2}{4 d^2}} \sqrt{c^2+\frac{8 d}{\sqrt{t}}-16 d}}$$

The pdf for $t$ becomes

$$\frac{2}{\pi} |J|=\left|\frac{2}{\pi  t^{3/2} \sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\left(\sqrt{c^2+\frac{8 d}{\sqrt{t}}-16 d}-c\right)^2}{4 d^2}\right) \left(c^2+\frac{8 d}{\sqrt{t}}-16 d\right)}}\right|$$

where $\frac{4}{(c+d+4)^2}<t<\frac{1}{4}$ and zero otherwise.